# PowerShell using a Foreach, if Statement and an array to import and export CSV

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to have PowerShell go through a CSV and remove anything that is in the “$skip” array then save the file. If I replace the $skip variable with the actual word on the IF line it will work, however when I use the variable nothing will be removed.

```
$file = "c:\temp\employee.csv"
$skip = "ax1","ax2","testdummy1"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties EmployeeID, Department,mailNickname |
Select-Object Name,mailNickname,UserPrincipalName,DistinguishedName,EmployeeID,Department `
| Export-Csv -Path $file

$list = foreach($line in Get-Content $file)
{
    IF($line -like $skip)
    {}
    Else 
    {$line}
}
$list| Set-Content $fileout -Force
```

Comment: Why not filter directly from your AD query instead of saving to a file and then reading from the file to do the exclusion? What attributes from AD are you looking to exclude ?

Comment: Are the lines you're wanting to skip matching exactly with those $skip values? Otherwise it will always be false without a wildcard

Comment: as others have mentioned, filter in your original pipeline. [*grin*] i would add a `Where-Object` pipeline stage, and use `-match` and convert your array of items to a regex OR pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `-match` for this.

```
$file = "c:\temp\employee.csv"
$skip = "ax1","ax2","testdummy1"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $ou -Properties EmployeeID, Department,mailNickname |
Select-Object Name,mailNickname,UserPrincipalName,DistinguishedName,EmployeeID,Department `
| Export-Csv -Path $file

$list = foreach($line in Get-Content $file)
{
    IF(($skip -match $line).Count -gt 0)
    {}
    Else 
    {$line}
}
$list| Set-Content $fileout -Force
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch